# Can I detect if a (node-webkit) window is visible?

Tags: node-webkit

I would like the user to be able to click on the system tray icon to hide a window if it is visible, or show it if it isn't.  However I can't see way to detect the show/hide state of the window.

I looked [here](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Window) but couldn't see anything that would give me what I need.  The only way seems to be to keep track of if my last call was to show() or to hide().  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I've needed this myself just recently, but as far as I know the best (only?) way is to set a boolean (e.g. *var showing = true;*) and then on every change (including the minimize and restore events) set the boolean to the correct value. Then you could simply make an if statement when clicking on the tray icon to see if the window is showing, and if it is hide the window, otherwise show it.

Hope I helped you a bit, I'm still looking for a better way myself but this is all I have found so far.